# How do I make my d3 graph fit responsively within my grid?

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, d3.js, css-grid

I have customised a donut chart for displaying with a grid layout. The grid has 3 different cards of same height in one row. But when i change the svg size manually from within the d3 component, the child  component in the grid overflows the grid-area I have specified for it, which is manageable at bigger screen sizes. But on laptop screens the edges of the svg get cut off as the edges are outside the boundaries of the grid view port.

I want the graph to scale down/up depending on how much of the grid viewport is available. I have also added the attribute preserveAspectRatio to the svg but that is not very helpful as the component width is too much.

Expected Grid behaviour:
[image: Grid when screen size is large]

When the screen width is reduced even a little bit:
[image: grid when screen width is reduced]

How do I make the d3 graph fit responsively within the grid?

EDIT: the code used;

grid.component.html

```
<div class="grid-container">
        <!-- Grid 1 -->
        <mat-card class="card">
          <mat-card-title-group>
            <mat-card-title>
              <div class="bold-font font-size-16 ml-15">Grid 1</div>
            </mat-card-title>
          </mat-card-title-group>
          <mat-card-content class="card-grid">
            <app-d3-donut class="card-grid-graph"></app-d3-donut>
          </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
</div>
```

grid-component.scss

```
.card-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 0.5fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.card-grid-graph {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 5 / 7;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}
```

The component I am using is app-d3-donut to render the donut graphs in the card.

d3-donut.component.html

```
  <div #donut></div>
```

d3-donut.component.scss

```
div{
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 140%;
}
```

d3-donut.component.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { D3Service } from '../services/d3.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-d3-donut',
  templateUrl: './d3-donut.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./d3-donut.component.scss']
})
export class D3DonutComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @Input('data') private data: SimpleDataModel[] = [
    { name: "Test String 1 25%", value: '25', color: '#254C66' },
    { name: `Test string 2 75%`, value: '75', color: '#49A0CC' },
  ];
  legend: any;
  private svg: any;
  private colors: any;
  @ViewChild('donut') figureElement: ElementRef;
  private d3: any;
  private margin = { top: 10, right: 0, bottom: 30, left: 0 };
  private width = 700;
  private height = 600;
  private radius = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2 - this.margin.left;

  graphGroup: any;
  constructor(private d3Service: D3Service) {
    this.d3 = d3Service.d3;
   }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.createSvg();
    this.createColors(this.data);
    this.createLegend();
    this.drawChart();
  }

  private createSvg(): void {
    this.d3
      .select(this.figureElement.nativeElement)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${this.width} ${this.height}`)
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet");

    this.svg = this.d3
    .select(this.figureElement.nativeElement)
    .select('svg');

    this.legend = this.svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('id','legend');
    
    this.graphGroup = this.svg
      .append('g')
      .attr(
        'transform',
        'translate(' + this.width / 2 + ',' + this.height / 2 + ')'
      );
  }

  private createLegend(): void {
    //code for creating the vertical legend at the top
  }

  private createColors(data): void {
    //code for generating random colors
  }

  private drawChart(): void {
    const pie = this.d3
      .pie()
      .sort(null) // Do not sort group by size
      .value(d => {
        return d.value;
      });
    const data_ready = pie(this.data);

    // The arc generator
    const arc = this.d3
      .arc()
      .innerRadius(this.radius * 0.4)
      .outerRadius(this.radius * 0.48);

    // code for building pie chart

    // code to add the lines between chart and labels:

    // code to add the labels:
    
}
```

The svg when inspected after resizing page:
[image: Svg that gets rendered in the grid]

Comment: Do you use a third-party component for yoyur Donut chart?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I am using the d3.js charting library but customised by me to make the donut graph as per the requirement, do you need its code?

Comment: Post any code relevent to the problem

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I think I have added all the relevant code, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

D3 graphs are usually rendered as SVG.
You could add some CSS to make them responsive:

```css
svg {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

Pretty much the same as for other images

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried this first before asking but since the svg is in another component, it is not working for some reason. Also the component is embedded into a grid, where if bigger, it just overflows the grid area. Could you take a look at the code I just added?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. On resize event, pass `width` and `height` of your grid cell to the component (by now they are constants, 700 and 600 respectively) and remove `viewBox`:

```
d3.select(...).append('svg').attr('width', this.width).attr('height', this.height);
```

2. Set SVG vidth and height as 100%, make `viewBox` constant (for example `0 0 100 100`) and set the donut radius constant (relative to the viewbox):

```
d3.select(...).append('svg').attr('viewBox', '0 0 100 100')
```

CSS:

```
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```